# iPhone SE -- Stocks App

Tags: iphone, ios, stocks.app

I have tried repeatedly to remove the chart in the stocks app from the screen. I scrolled up once to see a chart, and now I can't get the chart
to go away.

I can't get the chart in the attached screenshot 
to leave the screen.

[image]

How can I dismiss or hide the part where it says **Error retrieving chart**?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) As stated in its current form, your question isn't comprehensible. Consider [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/335283/edit) it to clearly state the query. Also consider attaching screenshots for better comprehension. Without the ability to understand clearly, a question attracts `unclear what you are asking` flags and may get closed.

Comment: Have you tried force-quitting the app (double-press the Home button, then swipe upwards on the app's mini-screen to quit the app), and then hard-restarting the iPhone (hold both Home and top buttons until you see the Apple logo) ?

Comment: Tried the hard reset and that didn't work. Force quit didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try is add a few more stocks and then the chart should be off screen. Also, when you tap on a specific index - it should take over with the appropriate chart.

If all the indexes are wrong, you might need to remove them and re-add what you need to see if the settings for the app are messed up somehow.

You can delete this app entirely and re-install it as well, so that's kind of a last resort item to try.

Comment: I deleted the app, reinstalled it, and a bunch more stocks were added to the indexes I have, but the chart is still there. When I tap on an index the chart appears to be correct.